# Delete rows with matching words in the same column, and matching values in multiple columns

Tags: r, string-matching, delete-row

I have a data frame with over 20000 rows (data3) with a Column named "collector". In this column I have strings of words, for example: "Ruiz Galvis Marta". I need to compare each row with all other rows in my data frame, and delete those rows in which one or more than one word in the column df$collector matches with the words in the same column in all other rows, and with the value in column "sample" and column "number". That is:

```
INPUT:

Collector                   Times     sample   number
Ruiz Galvis Marta            9         SP.1      one        
Smith et al Marta            8         SP.2      two
Ruiz Andres Allan            4         SP.1      one


EXPECTED OUTPUT

Collector                   Times     sample    number           
Smith et al Marta             8         SP.2      two
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably going to be slow as hell but

```
dd <- data.frame(Collector = c('Ruiz Galvis Marta', 'Smith et al Marta', 'Ruiz Andres Allan'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## create a matrix with the words by column
tt <- strsplit(dd$Collector, '\\s+')
mm <- do.call('rbind', lapply(tt, `length<-`, max(lengths(tt))))

## remove all duplicates
dd[rowSums(apply(mm, 2, function(x)
  duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE))) == 0, ]

# [1] "Smith et al Marta"
```

Comment: thanks this gave nice hints. I really didnt know where to start with this!